# Integration without making any substitution

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function

How do you integrate $$\dfrac{1}{(2+x^2)\cdot\sqrt{(1+x^2)}}$$ without making any substitution?
I don't know why I dislike substitution.

Comment: No matter if you like substitution or not, you will have to learn it if you want to compute integrals...

Comment: Is it impossible to do integration without substitution? How did substitution come to calculus? It doesn't look elementary to me.

Comment: @user571036 It’s possible to do some integrals *without* substitution—if you have the eye for it. A glaringly simple example might be $\int\frac{2\,dx}{x^2}$. The ability to **recognize** a solution without transforming it to perfectly align with prescribed ‘integral rules’ comes with **practice**. One of the ways to practice is by doing the substitution. There aren’t shortcuts to greatness, and math is like that too.

Answer (score 9):

You can get a solution without substitutions if you'll prove that
$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{x}{\sqrt{2(1+x^2)}}\right)'=\frac{1}{(2+x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2}}.$$